# Named Entity Extraction in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, opennlp

I am new to elasticsearch. I am exploring the possibility of extracting the entity from the content and index that in elasticsearch. I tried install and map the openNLP plugin in elasticsearch but ran into issues like no handler class found etc. I tried to build the openNLP plugin using maven but couldn't able to achieve the end objective.

Is there is other plugins available for named entity extraction in elasticsearch? Any other way to perform NER and indexing into ES if the not using the plugin.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, if you tried to use [this](https://github.com/spinscale/elasticsearch-opennlp-plugin) plugin, then this is the reason you run into problems. It is not used any more. I have found [this](https://github.com/YannBrrd/elasticsearch-entity-resolution) plugin, which I also intend to use and it seems promising, because it includes various kinds of comparators. So, depending on your text data, this plugin might help you recognize cities, persons etc.

If you don't mind performing the NER outside of ES and then incorporating the entities in your data, you can have a look at [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/136755/popular-named-entity-resolution-software) post for popular NER systems. Whichever algorithm you use to extract the entities, it is possible to create a new field in your ES index using POST and then fill in this field using the Update API.